# Require JS file in Chai TDD -- TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, tdd, mocha.js, chai

I'm new to using Chai for TDD. Wanted to run a function that I passed within a test file in Chai and check to see if its an object returned. Looks like I am not accessing the function right.

I get this in terminal when running the test -- 
"TypeError: parse is not a function"

parser.parse(xml) is a function in the parser.js file
parser.js has this pattern --

parser.js --

```
var VASTParser = {
  parse:function(xml) {
    return xml;
  },
  ...
};
```

parser-test.js --

```
var expect    = require("chai").expect;
var parser = require("../src/parser");

describe('VAST parsing from XML', function() {
    it('should take xml and parse to object', function() {
      var xmlStr = '<xml><stuff></stuff></xml>';
      var xmlObj = parser.parse(xmlStr.documentElement);
      expect(xmlObj).to.be.a('object');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not exported anything from your module. The way your `parser.js` module is setup, you could do:

```
var VASTParser = {
  parse:function(xml) {
    return xml;
  },
  ...
};

// Add this.
module.exports = VASTParser;
```

And then it should work.